# Question on using aws cli to deploy code to a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am looking at using jenkins to deploy a war file to an EC2 instance. I have set up similar before. Creating an EC2 instance, a S3 Bucket and a Code Deploy application. The way that worked was that :
1)zip up load the war/jar into a S3 Bucket.
2) Use AWS steps createDeployment to deploy the zip file from the S3 Bucket to the EC2. This would also involve creating a appspec.yml and scripts to set up the environment.

But have been told there is another way. that does not need setting up a code deploy.

I have created an Ec2 instance, set up a docker container inside it, with all the environment settings.

And what I would like to do is load my zip file into the EC2. That I dont need a AWS codedeploy application.

is this correct, is there a AWS CLI command to simply load a zip file into the EC2 instance.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There are basic Unix/Linux tools such as `scp` or `rsync` which can be used to copy files over a remote system.

Comment: The world has basically moved to continuous integration with automated deployment. Why do you want to go back to the era when deployable code was manually copied by a developer onto  a VM via cp/rsync/sftp etc?

Comment: Its using aws CLI as part of the Jenkins file so its still CI. But it seems a lot less complex than the other route. But I have moved away from this idea,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy from an s3 bucket

To copy files from a S3 bucket to EC2 instance,

1. Create an IAM role with S3 write access or admin access
2. Map the IAM role to an EC2 instance
3. Install AWS CLI in EC2 instance
4. Run the AWS s3 cp command to copy the files from S3 to EC2

To copy the files from S3 to EC2, Keep the source as the bucket URL and the destination to your local directory or filename

To copy the files from S3 to EC2
`aws s3 cp s3://<S3BucketName> <Fully Qualified Local filename/Directory>`
In the previous command, you can see the difference. Here the source is S3 Bucket URL and the destination is a local file name or directory name.

Comment: On #1, the policy would need read access to the specific objects, not write access and certainly not admin access. Also, note that many EC2 AMIs come with awscli pre-installed. That aside, while this approach can work, it's not ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have moved away from Ec2, to using a ECS. But I like your approach its pretty similar to the way I currently use code deploy. From the S3 Bucket to CodeDeploy. But in this case from a S3 Bucket straight to a Ec2 instance.